# Error 500 on pord mode but no on dev mode

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I tested my code in production mode and I am facing a 500 error which I don't understand since it occurs in production mode only and not in dev mode, moreover I have no error logs that occur manifest… from what I could tell it would come from $read since when I comment out the manager->flush(); the error disappears. However, the site database table is identical locally or on my server… here is the code in question (I leave the github link of the project below so that you can browse the different files in case it comes from elsewhere)

```
#[Route('/forum/topic/{id}', name: 'forum.topic', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function index(
    ForumTopic $topic,
    MemberRepository $memberRepository,
    ReadingRepository $readingRepository,
    ForumForumRepository $repositoryCategory,
    ForumForumRepository $repositoryForum,
    ForumTopicRepository $repositoryTopic,
    ForumPostRepository $repositoryPost,
    PaginatorInterface $paginator,
    EntityManagerInterface $manager,
    Request $request
): Response
{  
 
    if($this->getUser())
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $reading = $readingRepository->findOneBy(['user' => $user, 'topic' => $topic]);
         
        if ($reading === null) {
            $reading = new Reading();
            $reading->setUser($user);
            $reading->setTopic($topic);
        }
 
        $reading->setReadAt((new \DateTimeImmutable()));
 
        $manager->persist($reading);
        $manager->flush();
 
        $roles = $this->getUser()->getRoles();
         
        if (in_array('ROLE_MODERATOR', $roles)) {
            $categories = $repositoryCategory->findAll();
            $forums = $repositoryForum->findAll();
        }
    }
 
 
    /**
     * On récupère la liste des topics dans un arrray en fixant une limite à 20
     * @var array
     */
    $categories = null;
    $forums = null;
 
    $topic = $repositoryTopic->find(['id' => $topic]);
 
    // t = topic m = member mi = member_item
    $posts = $paginator->paginate(
        $repositoryPost
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t', 'mi', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('t.author', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('m.item', 'mi')
        ->orderBy('t.createAt')
        ->where('t.topic = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $topic->getId())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(),
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 20);
 
    // Sanitize each ForumPost object in the paginated results
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
        $posts[$key] = $this->htmlSanitizer->sanitizeObj($post);
    }
 
    $new_post = new ForumPost();
 
    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $new_post);
 
    $form->handleRequest($request);
 
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $new_post = $form->getData();
        $new_post->setAuthor($this->getUser());
        $new_post->setTopic($topic);
        $manager->persist($new_post);
 
        $topic->setUpdateAt(new \DateTimeImmutable());
        $manager->persist($topic);
 
        $memberRepository = $this->getUser();
        $memberRepository->setExperience($memberRepository->getExperience() + 5);
        $manager->persist($memberRepository);
 
        $this->addFlash(
            'info-rpg',
            '+5xp (post forum)'
        );
 
        $manager->flush();
 
        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Message créer avec succès'
        );
 
 
        return $this->redirectToRoute('forum.topic', ['id' => $topic->getId()]);
    }
 
    return $this->render($this->theme . '/forum/posts_list.html.twig', [
        'categories' => $categories,
        'forums' => $forums,
        'topic' => $topic,
        'posts' => $posts,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

link github project : https://github.com/MrToine/v2.univers-toine

thank's

i have testing on dev and on prod mode

Comment: Can you enable dev mode or profiler and check the error in the server and paste it here?

Comment: error 500 in productions is related to configuration error. Paste what is in your production log. Its located in YourApp/var/log/ its named prod.log